# Codeigniter ошибка url кириллица

Tags: url, codeigniter, utf-8

я в CI новичек. у меня стоит задача сделать все URLы на кириллице. в общем в конфиге поставила
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '?A-Za-zА-Яа-я=\s&0-9~%.:_-';
прописала все как было на форуме 
http://www.code-igniter.ru/forum/post22510.html
ввожу
site.com/такси и выдает ошибку 404 codeigniter
версия кодеигнайтера 3